# volume integral w/o or with cylinder coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I find the volume of the area which is bounded by the surface $z=4-x^2$ on the upperside, and the cylinder
$x^2+y^2=4$ and of the $xy$ plane on the underside.

I tried without using cylinder coordinates, since from $z=4-x^2$ then $z$ ranges from $0$ t0 $4-x^2$ and $x^2+y^2= 4 \Rightarrow x = \pm \sqrt{4-y^2}$ when $x=0$ we get that $y=\pm2$ then I integrate with all these boundaries

$$\iiint dzdxdy$$

Is this on the right track? or am I doing it wrong? Also how would I use cylinder coordinates instead if its possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to calculate the volume by both approaches. Next, for cylindrical coordinates we have: $x=\rho \cos \varphi, y = \rho \sin \varphi, z = z, J = \rho$, i.e.
$$V=\int \int \int \rho d\rho d\varphi dz.$$